# Remove the one trailing zero for a String datatype

Tags: java

How can i remove the only trailing zero for a string datatype in java. For Example:

if the input value is 29.360 then the expected output should be 29.36

if the input value is 29.00 then the expected output should be 29.0

if the input value is 29.50 then the expected output should be 29.5

Comment: What about `29.0`?  What have you tried already?

Comment: `if (string.charAt(string.length()-1) == '0') {string = string.substring(0, string.length()-1); }` Will remove `0` from the end of any String. It would however also turn `"100"` into `"10"` and `"2.0"` into `"2."`. But if that is not your intended behavior you should have specified so in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

- `"0$"` matches a `0` at the end of the string.
- and replaces all but that with an empty string if found.
- `(?<!\\.)` says don't remove a lone 0 after the decimal point.

```
String[] data = {"29.360", "100", "1000","29.00", "33.47", "29.50", "29.0"}; 
for (String val : data) {
    String result = val.replaceAll("(\\d*\\.\\d*)(?<!\\.)0$","$1");
    System.out.println(val + " --> " + result);
}
```

prints

```
29.360 --> 29.36
100 --> 100
1000 --> 1000
29.00 --> 29.0
33.47 --> 33.47
29.50 --> 29.5
29.0 --> 29.0
```

Comment: @Sandeep Same as the last question I told you on. if an answer solved you question, select it as the correct answer, do not just comment.

Answer (score -1):

You can use BigDecimal to achieve the same. Example is given below:

```
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("29.360").stripTrailingZeros());
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("29.00").stripTrailingZeros());
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("29.50").stripTrailingZeros());
```

Comment: I already tried this it is deleting all the zeros after decimal 29.00 would give you 29 but i need 29.0